# Pasteboard - copying (image + text) creates mystery \n line break

Tags: ios, objective-c, clipboard, line-breaks

When I add an image and a string to the pasteboard I get a mysterious line break at the start of my text?

```
NSMutableDictionary *photo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *text = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(theImage.image);
[photo setValue:imageData forKey:(NSString*)kUTTypePNG];
[text setValue:theText.text forKey:(NSString *)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText];
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:photo, text, nil]];
```

It puts the photo at the top and then it puts a line break and then the text. If I try to send the image and text in an iMessage the image separates anyways and I end up with the text in a bubble with a silly looking line-break infront of it.

If I just copy the text without the photo it does not add a mysterious line-break.

`[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:text, nil]];`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

*If not*, can anyone think of some nice workaround? Are there any unicode characters that will reverse a line-break? etc?

Comment: I'm trying to recreate this without success. I've created a new project with the exact same code as above. The image and text are pasted in the mail app & in iMessage almost perfectly. By almost I mean that if I'll paste "Testing this" the cursor will be before the last s. Not critical but still weird. Didn't got any line breaks. Maybe you can upload a sample project.

Comment: @Segev Did you press "send" after copy pasting the iMessage bubble in?

Comment: Yes. The text bubble looks normal. A quick search indicates that at least one other person experienced it, weird why I couldn't recreate it.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the size of the image used?

Comment: i also face this problem...if you got success in resolve this problem then can you elaborated it..

Answer (score 2):

Store PNG as BASE64 encode. See if this helps.